# How to select all elements in the DOM with same class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to implement multilanguage support to a website and for that I need to select all elements that have `class="lang"` attribute. This is how my Js code looks like

```
$(function(){
    var language = localStorage.getItem('language');
    if(language !== null){
        //this does not work
        $(document).find('.lang').each(function (index, element) {
            if($(this).attr('placeholder')!=null){
                //change placeholder text
            }
            $(this).text(arrLang[language][$(this).attr('key')]);
        });
    }

    //this works
    $(document).on('click','.translate',function () {
        var lang = $(this).attr('id');
        $(document).find('.lang').each(function (index, element) {
            if($(this).attr('placeholder')!=null){
                //change placeholder text
            }
            $(this).text(arrLang[lang][$(this).attr('key')]);
            localStorage.setItem('language',lang);
        });
    });
});
```

And this is the html code where Im trying to test this out

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <div class="navbar-brand">
                <img alt="brand" src="../img/th-logo.png" height="25px" width="60px" href="Startsite.jsp">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-brand">Studienlaufplan </div>
        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="../Startsite.jsp" class="lang" key="tasks" >Aufgaben</a> </li>
                <li><a href="../Account.jsp" class="lang" key="account" >Konto</a> </li>
                <li><a href="Canal.jsp" class="lang" key="cannals">Kanäle</a> </li>
                <li><a href="Settings.jsp" class="lang" key="settings">Einstellugen</a> </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="lang dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" key="language">Sprache</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#" class="translate" id="de">Deutsch</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="translate" id="en">English</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/Controller/Logout" class="lang" key="logout">Abmelden</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Im confused about jquery selectors and actually dont know how to use them well. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Don't make up your own attributes. Use `data-key` instead of `key`.

Comment: I don't see any difference between the code that works and the code that doesn't work. The only difference is that one runs when the page is first loaded, the other runs when when you click on something.

Comment: I recommend you move that similar code into a separate function, so you don't have to write it twice.

Comment: @Barmar I know its the same thats why I dont get why it isnt working

Comment: Are you loading the HTML dynamically? Maybe it's not loaded yet when the first code runs. Is language set in `localStorage`?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through it in the browser's debugger console, to see where it's failing?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I was loading that navbar dynamically and when I pasted the code with dynamic load it worked. That was the problem , thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

To get all elements with the specified class name, Try [document.getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName):-

`var x = document.getElementsByClassName("className");`

The `getElementsByClassName()` method is not supported in Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("example");
  x[0].innerHTML = "Hello World!";
  x[1].innerHTML = "my first code snippet"
}
```

```html
<div class="example">First div element with class="example".</div>

<div class="example">Second div element with class="example".</div>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

[try it yourself here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_document_getelementsbyclassname).

Comment: It'd be better if you add the JSFiddle (:

Comment: It would be even better if you used [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) instead of linking to an external site.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
$(".lang").each(function() {
    const $lang = $(this);
    // translate this item's text
});
```

Comment: @SebastianAmpueroMorisaki how is it not working? It should select all elements with class="lang"

Comment: You forgot the ) at the end.

Comment: @epascarello It doesnt show anything, I tried using getElementsByClassName and thats the only thing that worked for me but thats not how I want to do it